# Objectify v4 Ref.get() throwing ClassCastException

Tags: objectify

I have basically two classes:

```
@Entity 
class A {
   @Load
   Ref<B> other;

   public B getOther() {
      return other.get();
   }
}

@Entity
class B {
   ...
}
```

When I call someInstanceOfA.getOther() it throws:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity cannot be cast to objectify.example.B
```

I'm using objectify v 4.0b3.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @stickfigure! Yes, I register it into a ObjectifyFactory's constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the problem and I'm answering the question as it might happen to others. The bottom line is: My Guice container was injecting different objectify factories at different points, so I ended up having a context with all entities registered and another with no registered entities at all, the `ClassCastException` comes from this second situation.

Then I read [Jeff's recommendation](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Can_I_use_Dependency_Injection_%28Spring,_Guice,_Weld%29_with_Object) and changed my app to use static calls to Objectify instead of DI.

Now everything is working fine.

Comment: I was using Spring and I had the exact same problem. Removing DI and moving to Static import fixed it for me just like you said. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was registering my entities with the static method mentioned and I was still getting the error.
As mentioned in the FAQ of objectify this means that the entity was loaded before the class was registered as an entity. This seems like an objectify implementation issue.
So the simple but crude hack for me was to register the entity before the failing operation(OfyService.factory().register()) and it worked.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I start getting this error after changing the name of one entity class. Another entity had a Key referencing the old entity name. In this case you should update or save all entities that had a reference to the old entity name

Keep this in mind when you rename your entities